# How can I install Microsoft Office off of my subscription on my iPad?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, ipad

I purchased a Microsoft Office business subscription that would allow me to install Office on my iPad. However, I met with a surprise when trying to log in to the appropriate website, http://cjshayward.onmicrosoft.com. The name did not resolve. I thought I'd try to log in to http://onmicrosoft.com, but that didn't resolve either.

How can I install Office off of my subscription on my iPad now?

Comment: What makes you think `http://cjshayward.onmicrosoft.com/` or `http://www.onmicrosoft.com/` are a valid domains?

Comment: Previous use, and the URLs being given in an autogenerated "Here's your information" email from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The login error is because the domain does not exist according to any DNS. 
The supported way is to download the Office apps separately from the app store. Once downloaded, you must sign in, and that will activate Office. The install instructions are detailed below:

### Install and set up Office on an iPhone or iPad with Office 365

> ### Install and sign in to any Word, Excel, PowerPoint, or OneNote app on an iPhone or iPad for the first time
>
> Your device must be running iOS 8.0 or later. App availability also
>   varies by country. [Find out what's available in your country](http://products.office.com/en-us/mobile/device-availability-worldwide)
>
> ***Important***
>
> To use the [extra features](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-resources) in the apps, you must sign in with the Microsoft account or work or school account that's
>   associated with your qualifying Office 365 subscription. If you have
>   an iPad Pro, you must also have a qualifying plan to do any type of
>   editing on that particular device. See [What you can do in the Office apps on an iOS or Android device with an Office 365 plan.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-can-do-in-the-Office-apps-on-an-iOS-or-Android-device-with-an-Office-365-plan-9ef8b63a-05fd-4f9c-bac5-29da046833ea)
>
> To learn more about Office apps on the iPad Pro, see the Office blog
>   post [Microsoft Office apps are ready for the iPad Pro.](https://blogs.office.com/2015/11/11/microsoft-office-apps-are-ready-for-the-ipad-pro/)
>
> If you haven't installed any of the Office apps on your iPhone or iPad
>   as yet, download one, or all of them from the Apple App Store.
>
> [Word](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id586447913)
>
> [Excel](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id586683407)
>
> [PowerPoint](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id586449534)
>
> [OneNote](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id478105721)
>
> Once you download it, tap any Office app to open it. Swipe through the
>   introduction, and tap Sign In.
>
> To use the [extra features](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id478105721) in the app, on the Sign in page, type the
>   personal Microsoft account or work or school account associated with
>   your Office 365 subscription, and then tap Next.

Source: [Microsoft Office Helpdesk Article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-and-set-up-Office-on-an-iPhone-or-iPad-with-Office-365-9df6d10c-7281-4671-8666-6ca8e339b628)